# How to find and tar files then delete them

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, tar

I need to find files that are older than 30 days, tar and compress them and remove the ones that I already tar and compressed.

I was trying to execute something like this but it does not look like its working

```
find /u01/oracle/files -mtime +30 -exec tar -czvf filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz /u01/oracle/files {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The command doesn't work because `find` invokes a new `tar` instance for every file it finds, and each `tar` instance overwrites the archive file with a new one containing only the one file that it got supplied by `find`. What you want is for `find` to assemble a complete list of all files, then pass that list onto a single `tar`:

```
find /u01/oracle/files -mtime +30 -print0 | tar -czvf filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --null -T /dev/stdin
```

If your version of `tar` supports it, add the `--remove-files` flag to remove source files that were successfully compressed.

If your `tar` does not support this flag, you can use this script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
filelist="$(mktemp)"
find /u01/oracle/files -mtime +30 -print0 > "$filelist"
tar -czvf "filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz" --null -T "$filelist"
xargs -0 rm < "$filelist"
rm "$filelist"
```

Using a temporary file to store the list instead of regenerating it prevents a condition where a file might not be considered old enough for the `tar` command, but by the time the archive was created, time has passed and more files match.

Make sure to include the `-e` in the shebang (first line). If you omit it, bash will ignore errors of the commands it executes, potentially leading to data loss.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try running the last one

Comment: oracle$ find /u01/oracle/files -mtime +60 -print0 > /tmp/filelist.txt tar -czvf filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --null -T /tmp/filelist.txt xargs -0 rm < /tmp/filelist.txt rm /tmp/filelist.txt
find: paths must precede expression: tar
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: @R_Mat I have improved and clarified the answer about that part, please see the edited code.

Comment: #!/bin/bash -e
filelist="$(mktemp)"
find /u01/oracle/files/*.aud -mtime +30 -print0 > "$filelist"
tar -czvf "filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz" --null -T "$filelist"
xargs -0 rm < "$filelist"
rm "$filelist"

Comment: When I run it like that above I get this error

Comment: rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

Comment: This probably means that there weren't any files found. Try running just the `find` command without anything else, and removing the `-print0 > $filelist` part so that it outputs to console. (You probably meant to call it like `find /u01/oracle/files -name '*.aud' -mtime ...`.)